# Windows Server 2008 dropping connections

Tags: windows-server-2008, firewall, nat, connection

Possible quite similar to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/353810/windows-server-2008-r2-drops-packets) post but I wonder if someone can help me with this issue.

**Home Server specs:**
Windows Server 2008 Standard (Non-R2)
2 NICs, external one(Realtek) has a firewall on it. The internal one(Nvidia) runs NAT for my home computers.
Cable modem issuing an internal ip to my server (192.168.178.10)(Modem is not the issue, problem was there before this setup)

The problem is that sometimes programs that require a connection to my server either fail to setup a working connection, or that connections get dropped randomly.

**Afflicted programs:**
- Mumble(Voice program like teamspeak) - gets disconnected after a few seconds and then reconnects automatically every minute.(reconnecting is a program setting, the disconnecting is not)
- Self programmed apps in VS2010 - Can at first not connect to my SQL Server 2005 DB on the server, but after some time (minutes) they can
- FTP Server on the Server itself - Remote clients can either not log in, or the download stops and the connection gets dropped? after a few seconds of transferring

This problem occurs only with some applications, all other traffic like Squeezebox, file transfer, RDP and http traffic to the server and the internet from clients works fine.

In the beginning I thought the problem was an incorrect firewall setting, but I have allowed all ports and traffic in the config between server and clients. Now im beginning to suspect NAT of being at fault here, but I don't know for sure.

After examining the problem in the question linked above, I checked my servers config and it looked similar to that one. Can anyone see any problematic settings in the ipconfig below which might explain the problem?

```
Output ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Server
Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : Yes
WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Internet NIC:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek RTL8169/8110 Family PCI Gigabit E
thernet NIC (NDIS 6.0)
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-11-6B-97-D8-20
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::4d4e:d07d:1b3:3139%13(Preferred)
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.178.10(Preferred)
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : vrijdag 13 april 2012 10:47:27
Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : donderdag 19 april 2012 10:18:21
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.178.1
DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.178.1
DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 419434859
DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-11-D4-40-5D-00-10-A7-02-20-B3

DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 212.54.40.25
                                    212.54.35.25
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Thuisnetwerk NIC:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : NVIDIA nForce 10/100/1000 Mbps Ethernet
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-24-8C-76-7D-5B
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::29e1:cbe0:aded:4918%11(Preferred)
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.10.10.10(Preferred)
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 0.0.0.0
DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 268444812
DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-11-D4-40-5D-00-10-A7-02-20-B3

DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.10.10.10
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 8:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : isatap.{76229E8E-F1F4-49AD-83AE-7CD4AABB2
A2B}
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 9:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : isatap.{A2CF8243-DD8B-407C-A8AF-292D0E410
A03}
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 11:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 02-00-54-55-4E-01
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:5ef5:79fd:2454:1613:abe0:cd40(Pref
erred)
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::2454:1613:abe0:cd40%12(Preferred)
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

Output route print 0.0.0.0
===========================================================================
Interface List
 13 ...00 11 6b 97 d8 20 ...... Realtek RTL8169/8110 Family PCI Gigabit Ethernet
 NIC (NDIS 6.0)
 11 ...00 24 8c 76 7d 5b ...... NVIDIA nForce 10/100/1000 Mbps Ethernet
  1 ........................... Software Loopback Interface 1
 14 ...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0  isatap.{76229E8E-F1F4-49AD-83AE-7CD4AABB2A2B}
 15 ...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0  isatap.{A2CF8243-DD8B-407C-A8AF-292D0E410A03}
 12 ...02 00 54 55 4e 01 ...... Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination  Netmask          Gateway       Interface       Metric
0.0.0.0              0.0.0.0          On-link       10.10.10.10     266
0.0.0.0              0.0.0.0          192.168.178.1 192.168.178.10  10
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
Network Address      Netmask          Gateway Address               Metric
0.0.0.0              0.0.0.0          10.10.10.10                   Default
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
None
Persistent Routes:
None
```

Comment: all the adapters are set to auto for speed/duplex correct?

Comment: Yes they all have the default values, except the Thuisnetwerk(Internal network) NIC. This one has a static ip of 10.10.10.10 and subnetmask of 255.255.255.0. This is the one that does NAT.

Comment: well auto for speed/duplex has nothing to do with ip address stuff so are the adapters set to auto and the switch ports set to auto?

Comment: Yes its all set to auto negotiate, the connected switch aswell.

Comment: Questions about home systems are off topic on Server Fault - You would do better asking this question on our sister site for enthusiast/home users: [Super User](http://www.superuser.com)

Answer (score 1):

Try turning off the TCP Chimney and the receive window autotuning.

From an Administrative command prompt:

```
netsh int tcp set global chimney=disabled

netsh int tcp set global autotuninglevel=disabled
```

Answer (score 0):

Hate to say it but have you tried disabling the firewall to eliminate it from the search ? I have had all kinds of crazy issues with the 2008 firewall.

Comment: Yeah that was my first idea aswell, but that didn't solve the problem. The firewall is also not activated on the internal network, so shouldnt even be a problem. I've spent many hours trying to fix the problems with a different firewall setup, but to no avail. I'm thinking of disabling the firewall and NAT on the server totally, and reenabling NAT/Firewall/DHCP on my modem to circumvent the problem.

Comment: Tried doing a pathping to your router from a client or a pingtest.net from a client ?

Comment: Pathping is not showing anything out of the ordinary, 100% succes and all in one hop, like it should be. Pingtest.net shows 15ms, which is good but cant test the packetloss. In the description it is said this might be due to outgoing firewall blocking, which is strange in this case as there shouldnt be any.

Comment: Update of last comment: After updating java it was ok, it now shows 0% loss. Still can't figure out what the problem might be.

Comment: Does the Nvidia adapter have the admin interface if you connect to it ? I have had issues with them in the past.